# Python formatting elements in an array with regex

Tags: python, arrays, regex, scripting

Using Python 2.6.6, I'm trying to format each element in a list using regex.

Example of elements in an array:

```
test1;apple;-fgnsldfgsbfdgb
test2;watermelon;-iwerunvfgkjsfg
test3;orange;wervxddgjbdhnf
```

I'd like to format the text to just grab what is in between the semicolons ;

```
apple
watermelon
orange
```

The regex to capture that is the following:

```
(?<=\;)(.*?)(?=\;)
```

I tried different variations of the following code:

```
for member in fruits:
    parseFruit = re.compile(member)
    member = member.sub( (\.),((?<=\;)(.*?)(?=\;)) )
    print("Fruit: ", member)
```

Nothing seems to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data, instead of sub you can use search without a capturing group to get the first match.

[`(?<=;).*?(?=;)`](https://regex101.com/r/TA5tXV/1)

```
fruits = ['test1;apple;-fgnsldfgsbfdgb',
'test2;watermelon;-iwerunvfgkjsfg',
'test3;orange;wervxddgjbdhnf']

for member in fruits:
    print ("Fruit: " + re.search("(?<=;).*?(?=;)", member).group(0))
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/BQDLQ62992)

If you want to use [sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), you could match from the beginning of the string till the first occurence of `;` and then als match that. Or match the last occurence of `;` till the end of the string. Then replace that with an empty string.

[`^[^;]+;|;[^;]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/TA5tXV/2)

```
for member in fruits:
    print("Fruit: " + re.sub(r'^[^;]+;|;[^;]+$', '', member))
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/ZUO41161)

Comment: Sorry, I initially wrote lists in the title but it should have been array. I'm not sure if this changes anything but when I tried it, it prints it fine but the change doesn't keep.

Comment: This works great! I had to add a "member =" instead of the "print" to keep the change, thank you!

Comment: Actually when I do a print(fruits) it prints it the original way... is there a write or save command I'm missing ?

Comment: @Awsmike In the example the result of each operation is printed but fruits itself is not modified. If you want to change `fruits` you might use [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) ([Demo](http://rextester.com/UWKYA36577)) or store the result in a new list ([Demo](http://rextester.com/PSARNT40467))

Comment: Thank You, I ended up doing just that, creating a new list and using newlist.append(member) for anyone who was interested...

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

s = """test1;apple;-fgnsldfgsbfdgb
test2;watermelon;-iwerunvfgkjsfg
test3;orange;wervxddgjbdhnf"""

fruits = re.findall(r';(.*?);', s)

for fruit in fruits:
    print('Fruit: %s' % fruit)

#fruits is ['apple', 'watermelon', 'orange']
```

Output:

```
Fruit: apple
Fruit: watermelon
Fruit: orange
```

Comment: Sorry, I initially wrote lists in the title but it should have been array. I'm not sure if this changes anything but when I tried it, it prints it fine but the change doesn't keep

Comment: In variable `fruits` you have `['apple', 'watermelon', 'orange']`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of using regex you can use the split function

```
FruitList= ['test1;apple;-fgnsldfgsbfdgb', 'test2;watermelon;-iwerunvfgkjsfg', 'test3;orange;wervxddgjbdhnf']
Fruits= [i.split(';')[1::2] for i in FruitList]
```

> `[['apple'], ['watermelon'], ['orange']]`